# Scaling an image with a Vector2 less than zero

Tags: c#, collision-detection, monogame, rectangles

I'm currently working on a project and I'm trying to scale an image down.
I have a hitbox determined by the following code.

```
public Rectangle bound
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, 
                texture.Width * (int)scale.X,
                texture.Height * (int)scale.Y);
        }
    }
```

This works assuming the scale is either one or greater. However, when I input a scale value less than one collisions don't work and the Console.WriteLine() function returns {X:300 Y:300 Width:0 Height:0}. 
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Casting to `int` truncates, so `0.9` goes to `0`. Try casting *after* multiplying instead: `(int)(texture.Width * scale.X)`

Comment: Figured it out right before I saw your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well don't I feel silly.

```
public Rectangle bound
    {
        get
        {
            return texture == null ? new Rectangle(0,0,0,0) : new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y,
                (int)(texture.Width * scale.X), (int)(texture.Height * scale.Y));
        }
    }
```

Apparently if your rectangle's dimensions are a float it returns a zero.